# Eclipse Java Employee Phone program

Tags: java

Employee Phone program compiled in Eclipse with error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        at pcsettingfirstpj.Ch8_1_1.main(Employee.java:34)
```

with program:

```
package pcsettingfirstpj;

public class Employee {
    private char name;
    private Phone list;
    class Phone {
        private long home, cell;
        public Phone(long phone1, long phone2){
            home = phone1;  cell = phone2;
        }
        public void printPhone(){
            System.out.println("Tel (Home 2): " + home);
            System.out.println("Tel (Mobile 2): " + cell);
        }
    }

    public Employee(char name, long home, long cell){
        this.name = name;
        list = new Phone(home, cell);
    }

    public void printEmployee(){
        System.out.println("====Staff====");
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Tel (Home 1): " + list.home);
        System.out.println("Tel (Mobile 1): " + list.cell);
        list.printPhone();
    }
}

public class Ch8_1_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Employee joe = new Employee('a',28456789L, 936555552L);
        Employee jane = new Employee('b',23134563L,938444444L);
        joe.printEmployee();
        jane.printEmployee();
    }
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly, that's `public class Ch8_1_1 {`

Comment: Is this code all in one file? You can't have multiple classes defined at the same level in one file.

Comment: how can you define two public classes in one file?

Comment: In Java you can't define two public classes in same file. And also make sure you have given the same names to only public class and the file (e.g. public Demo class in Demo.java file, and this Demo.java may contain another Abc class but not any public Abc class) hope it will work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following these steps:

1. Put both classes in separate file :`Ch8_1_1.java` and `Employee.java` maybe in the same package.
2. Run the class `Ch8_1_1.java` as java application with your IDE.

The issue was you have more than one public class in the same file.java

Comment: Oh yes, I put them in separate file that would be ok.  Thanks :)
What's package `pcsettingfirstpj;`?  Could I use other package?

Answer (score 3):

It would seem you have defined multiple public classes in a single file, which results in a compile error because Java cannot compile two adjacent public classes in the same file. If this is your intention, then you can remove the `public` modifier to make it [package-private](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Name this file `Ch8_1_1.java`.

```
public class Ch8_1_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee joe = new Employee('a', 28456789L, 936555552L);
        Employee jane = new Employee('b', 23134563L, 938444444L);
        joe.printEmployee();
        jane.printEmployee();
    }
}

class Employee {

    private char name;
    private Phone list;

    class Phone {
        private long home, cell;

        public Phone(long phone1, long phone2) {
            home = phone1;
            cell = phone2;
        }

        public void printPhone() {
            System.out.println("Tel (Home 2): " + home);
            System.out.println("Tel (Mobile 2): " + cell);
        }
    }

    public Employee(char name, long home, long cell) {
        this.name = name;
        list = new Phone(home, cell);
    }

    public void printEmployee() {
        System.out.println("====Staff====");
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Tel (Home 1): " + list.home);
        System.out.println("Tel (Mobile 1): " + list.cell);
        list.printPhone();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a class is defined as public class then it should be in a file with the same name..

Eg: public class Employee

FileName : Employee.java

In you case Employee is public so therefore compiler wants it to be Employee.java to produce `Employee.class` ..But in the same Class you have one more public class `Ch8_1_1`, so it also wants the filename to be `Ch8_1_1.java` to produce `Ch8_1_1.class` which cant happen..

So declare `Employeee` as `class Employee` without **public** modifier..

Dont declare two public classes in the same file..

```
package pcsettingfirstpj;

class Employee {

private char name;
private Phone list;
class Phone {
    private long home, cell;
    public Phone(long phone1, long phone2){
        home = phone1;  cell = phone2;
    }
    public void printPhone(){
        System.out.println("Tel (Home 2): " + home);
        System.out.println("Tel (Mobile 2): " + cell);
    }
}

public Employee(char name, long home, long cell){
    this.name = name;
    list = new Phone(home, cell);
}

public void printEmployee(){
    System.out.println("====Staff====");
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Tel (Home 1): " + list.home);
    System.out.println("Tel (Mobile 1): " + list.cell);
    list.printPhone();
}
}

public class Ch8_1_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Employee joe = new Employee('a',28456789L, 936555552L);
    Employee jane = new Employee('b',23134563L,938444444L);
    joe.printEmployee();
    jane.printEmployee();
}
```

}